# Migrate from HFS+ to APFS in-place

Tags: macos, apfs

Using **macOS Sierra**, how do I migrate/switch/transition/upgrade the boot volume/partition from HFS+ to APFS *in-place*?

Is this advisable, or perhaps already done by the *Sierra installer*?

Comment: You can't APFS does not work on the boot volume yet http://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/09/macos-10-12-sierra-the-ars-technica-review/7/#h1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Jun 2017 according to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html), during macOS High Sierra install, file system can be upgraded from HFS+ to APFS:

> **How do I upgrade to Apple File System?**
>
> The macOS 10.13 installer offers nondestructive in-place upgrades from
>   HFS+ to APFS for bootable volumes. You can use Disk Utility to convert
>   external volumes from HFS+ to APFS format.

Answer (score 8):

*Note: this was true before the announcement of High Sierra, June '17*

You cannot use APFS as a boot volume for Sierra, it's not yet supported.

APFS is still in development & will be capable of being used as a boot volume when it's finally released.

From [Apple File System Guide - FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html) ...

> **Can I boot macOS Sierra from an APFS-formatted hard disk?**
>
> No. macOS Sierra supports Apple File System for data volumes only. You
>   cannot boot macOS Sierra from a APFS-formatted volume.
>
> **How do I upgrade to Apple File System?**
>
> Apple will offer nondestructive in-place upgrades from HFS+ to APFS
>   for all boot volumes when Apple File System ships in 2017. Tools will
>   be available to convert external volumes from HFS+ to APFS format.

Comment: Apparently that's no longer strictly true: https://twitter.com/TylerLoch/status/834096712717332480 Seems like a very risky procedure though.

Comment: @UloPe -  I'd rather stick pins in my eyes, really ;) I'll wait for it to be officially supported. They already  changed the structure between 10.12.1 & 10.12.2 [iirc] & broke any drive already using APFS as non-boot...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this in September 2017 -- even as of High Sierra beta 13 it still doesn't seem possible to convert an HFS+ Journaled boot drive "in-place" to APFS.  The options are still grayed out in the Disk Utility if you try.

Comment: The option is grayed out in 10.13.1 if the drive is mounted, but not if it is unmounted. Go figure. But when unmounted, the conversion in place fails …