# Change from Mac OS Extended File to APFS in order to install Mojave

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mojave, mac-mini

I've tried to install Mac OS Mojave on my Mac Mini (late 2012), but it has Mac OS Extended (journaled) as the file system on the main drive. [This link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253984/migrate-from-hfs-to-apfs-in-place) is somewhat inconclusive and refers to retired documents.

So my question is two-folded:

1. Can I change in-place from Mac OS Extended (journaled) to APFS on my boot disc (and can Mojave boot from APFS)?
2. If not, how can I install Mojave on my Mac Mini (which currently runs High Sierra)?

*Update:* I've already tried upgrading, and it failed with a vague error message related to the file system upgrade (which I sadly can't recall).

Comment: Would you be interested in a command line install to force the logging and conversation from HFS+ to APFS along with the upgrade? There will be an answer or an error message indicating what failed if you script the OS upgrade. Probably can find the `/var/log/install.log` as well from a normal install if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

The internal drives of Macs are converted to APFS when upgrading to macOS 10.14 Mojave and yes, macOS Mojave boots from APFS just fine.

More specifically, when Mojave is installed it will convert any internal drive (including SSDs, HDDs and Fusion/Hybrid Drives) from HFS Plus to APFS.

This is an important distinction as prior to macOS Mojave, only SSDs were converted to APFS, and this explains some of the confusion over time regarding how macOS Sierra, macOS High Sierra and macOS Mojave have managed things as APFS has continued to evolve.

Comment: I did already try to upgrade, and the upgrade failed on this file system upgrade. So I need to do something different, in order for it to work. But what, that is the question...

Comment: Add the symptoms of what exactly fails and how to your original question. It *could be* a file system or HDD/SSD error.

Comment: How much free space is on the drive that needs to be updated?

Comment: @IconDaemon, There is 654 GB available (out of a total of 999GB) on the main HDD (and even more on the other HDD).

Answer (score -1):

If you still can't update, you can try dosdude1's patcher at http://dosdude1.com/mojave.

Comment: The OP has a Late 2012 Mac mini, which already supports macOS Mojave, so I fail to see why a patcher is needed! That said... We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.